# Inserir elementos em vetor de listas C++

Tags: c++

Não estou conseguindo inserir elementos em um vetor de lista. O programa imprime a variável quantidade_de_vertices e então ocorre um erro de tempo de execução.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *arq = fopen(argv[1], "r") ;
    int quantidade_de_vertices, vertice1, vertice2, cont;
    
    fscanf(arq, "%*c %*s %d %*d", &quantidade_de_vertices);
    cout << quantidade_de_vertices;

    vector< list<int> > adj(quantidade_de_vertices);

    while(!feof(arq)){
        fscanf(arq, "%*c %d %d", &vertice1, &vertice2);
        adj[vertice1].push_back(vertice2); //essa é a linha com o erro
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

Aparentemente o problema esta no operador [] da função vetor que não esta aceitando a variável vertice1, pois quando eu testei trocando a linha:

> adj[vertice1].push_back(vertice2);

por

> adj[1].push_back(vertice2);

e o programa executou normalmente.
Os arquivos estão formatados da seguinte forma:

> p edge 4 6
>
> e 1 2
>
> e 1 3
>
> e 1 4
>
> e 2 3
>
> e 2 4
>
> e 3 4
>
> EOF

Answer (score 2):

O problema está no `fscanf` e na leitura do termino de linha, o `\n`.

Na primeira linha funciona bem, e lê os 4 valores mas na segunda linha, através de *debug* rapidamente se vê que a leitura não funcionou bem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em que o `vertice2` ficou com `4201420` e o `vertice1` com `2686760`.

Isto porque o `\n` da primeira linha não foi consumido e estragou as sucessivas leituras. Logo a solução é simples, basta alterar o primeiro `fscanf` para:

```
fscanf(arq, "%*c %*s %d %*d\n", &quantidade_de_vertices); //agora com \n no fim
```

E o que está dentro do `while` também:

```
fscanf(arq, "%*c %d %d\n", &vertice1, &vertice2); //também com \n
```

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar, não é aconselhável misturar operações de e/s C++ (cin/cout) e C (printf/scanf), você precisar se tratar erros de duas coisas (C++ e C) ao invés de uma só (C++ ou C).

Em segundo lugar, quando se usa scanf/fscanf/sscanf em sistemas de produção (e não apenas em programinhas de teste e exercícios) é necessário SEMPRE verificar o resultado de scanf, para tratar os erros que possam ter ocorrido.

Abaixo eu modifiquei o programa original para mostrar o resultado do fscanf.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int quantidade_de_vertices, vertice1, vertice2, cont;

  FILE* arq = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  int n_cpos_lidos;

  n_cpos_lidos = fscanf(arq, "%*c %*s %d %*d", &quantidade_de_vertices);
  cout << "* cpos lidos: " << n_cpos_lidos << " / n_vertices: " << quantidade_de_vertices << '\n';

  vector< list<int> > adj(quantidade_de_vertices);

  while (!feof(arq))
  {
    n_cpos_lidos = fscanf(arq, "%*c %d %d", &vertice1, &vertice2);
    cout << "* inserindo: cpos lidos: " << n_cpos_lidos << " / v1: " << vertice1 << " / v2: " << vertice2 << '\n';
    adj[vertice1].push_back(vertice2); //essa é a linha com o erro
  }

  cout << "* eof\n";

  fclose(arq);
  return 0;
}
```

Rodando esse programa com os dados mostrados na pergunta (inclusive com o EOF que não sei se realmente está no arquivo, ou se é só uma indicação de fim de arquivo *na pergunta*).

O resultado é este:

```
~/Projects/testes/so]
$./223533 dados_223533.txt 
* cpos lidos: 1 / n_vertices: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 0 / v2: 32662
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 2
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 1 / v2: 2
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 1 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 1 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 2 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 2 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 2 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 2 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: -1 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* eof

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

Percebe-se que ocorreram muitas falhas na leitura, o programa e o arquivo estão fora de sincronismo. Como explicado na outra resposta, isso é causado pelos caracteres de fim de linha.

Uma maneira simples de mitigar o problema de fim de linha neste programa é colocar um espaço antes da leitura do primeiro caracter. Mudar `fscanf(arq, "%*c %*...` para `fscanf(arq, " %*c %*...`. Aquele espaço antes do "%c" consome os caracteres de fim de linha que porventura possam existir.

O programa fica agora assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int quantidade_de_vertices, vertice1, vertice2, cont;

  FILE* arq = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  int n_cpos_lidos;

  n_cpos_lidos = fscanf(arq, " %*c %*s %d %*d", &quantidade_de_vertices);
  cout << "* cpos lidos: " << n_cpos_lidos << " / n_vertices: " << quantidade_de_vertices << '\n';

  vector< list<int> > adj(quantidade_de_vertices);

  while (!feof(arq))
  {
    n_cpos_lidos = fscanf(arq, " %*c %d %d", &vertice1, &vertice2);
    cout << "* inserindo: cpos lidos: " << n_cpos_lidos << " / v1: " << vertice1 << " / v2: " << vertice2 << '\n';
    adj[vertice1].push_back(vertice2); //essa é a linha com o erro
  }

  cout << "* eof\n";

  fclose(arq);
  return 0;
}
```

O resultado agora é este:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./223533 dados_223533.txt 
* cpos lidos: 1 / n_vertices: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 2
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 2 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 2 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 0 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: -1 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* eof

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

Quase certo! Tem aquele problema no final, com n_cpos_lidos igual a 0 e a -1, que o programa não está tratando. O primeiro problema n_cpos_lidos igual a 0, com certeza é causado por aquele EOF no final do arquivo. Tirando o EOF do arquivo o resultado fica assim:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./223533 dados_223533.txt 
* cpos lidos: 1 / n_vertices: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 2
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 2 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 2 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: -1 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* eof

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

Melhorou, mas ainda tem aquele "cpos lidos: -1" que o programa não está tratando direito. A causa deste erro é que o programa está tratando o fim de arquivo de maneira errada: o tratamento de fim de arquivo deve ser feito imediatamente após o fscanf, e não de volta no início do loop. A modificação para fazer o tratamento da maneira certa fica assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int quantidade_de_vertices, vertice1, vertice2, cont;

  FILE* arq = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  int n_cpos_lidos;

  n_cpos_lidos = fscanf(arq, " %*c %*s %d %*d", &quantidade_de_vertices);
  cout << "* cpos lidos: " << n_cpos_lidos << " / n_vertices: " << quantidade_de_vertices << '\n';

  vector< list<int> > adj(quantidade_de_vertices);

  for (;;)
  {
    n_cpos_lidos = fscanf(arq, " %*c %d %d", &vertice1, &vertice2);
    if ( n_cpos_lidos != 2)
    {
      if (feof(arq))
        cout << "* fim de arquivo\n";
      else
        cout << "* erro de formato na leitura\n";
     break;
    }
    cout << "* inserindo: cpos lidos: " << n_cpos_lidos << " / v1: " << vertice1 << " / v2: " << vertice2 << '\n';
    adj[vertice1].push_back(vertice2); //essa é a linha com o erro
  }

  fclose(arq);
  return 0;
}
```

A saída agora fica assim:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./223533 dados_223533.txt 
* cpos lidos: 1 / n_vertices: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 2
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 1 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 2 / v2: 3
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 2 / v2: 4
* inserindo: cpos lidos: 2 / v1: 3 / v2: 4
* fim de arquivo

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

O funcionamento agora está correto, com os dados fornecidos na pergunta.